# Power BI couting

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to create a measure that will count values from the table below. How can I count projects that have at least one task and date and how can I count projects that have two tasks and dates?

Bonus question: how can I count projects that have at least one task and no date (null) and how can I count projects with two tasks done and no dates?

[image]

Comment: Do you need flags in each row? Or overall counts from the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here below 4 measures is for you-

**1.**

```
one_one = 

var count_task_1 = IF(min(project_count[task 1]) <> BLANK() && MIN(project_count[date 1]) <> BLANK(),1,0)
var count_task_2 = IF(min(project_count[task 2]) <> BLANK() && MIN(project_count[date 2]) <> BLANK(),1,0)
var count_task_3 = IF(min(project_count[task 3]) <> BLANK() && MIN(project_count[date 3]) <> BLANK(),1,0)

RETURN
IF(
    (count_task_1+count_task_2+count_task_3) >= 1,
    1,
    0
)
```

**2.**

```
two_two = 

var count_task_1 = IF(min(project_count[task 1]) <> BLANK() && MIN(project_count[date 1]) <> BLANK(),1,0)
var count_task_2 = IF(min(project_count[task 2]) <> BLANK() && MIN(project_count[date 2]) <> BLANK(),1,0)
var count_task_3 = IF(min(project_count[task 3]) <> BLANK() && MIN(project_count[date 3]) <> BLANK(),1,0)

RETURN
IF(
    (count_task_1+count_task_2+count_task_3) >= 2,
    1,
    0
)
```

**3.**

```
one_no_date = 

var count_task_1 = IF(min(project_count[task 1]) <> BLANK() && MIN(project_count[date 1]) = BLANK(),1,0)
var count_task_2 = IF(min(project_count[task 2]) <> BLANK() && MIN(project_count[date 2]) = BLANK(),1,0)
var count_task_3 = IF(min(project_count[task 3]) <> BLANK() && MIN(project_count[date 3]) = BLANK(),1,0)

RETURN
IF(
    (count_task_1+count_task_2+count_task_3) >= 1,
    1,
    0
)
```

**4.**

```
two_no_date = 

var count_task_1 = IF(min(project_count[task 1]) <> BLANK() && MIN(project_count[date 1]) = BLANK(),1,0)
var count_task_2 = IF(min(project_count[task 2]) <> BLANK() && MIN(project_count[date 2]) = BLANK(),1,0)
var count_task_3 = IF(min(project_count[task 3]) <> BLANK() && MIN(project_count[date 3]) = BLANK(),1,0)

RETURN
IF(
    (count_task_1+count_task_2+count_task_3) >= 2,
    1,
    0
)
```

Here is the output-

[image]

> **You can do your other necessary calculation using these logics**